# Linqで取得したデータごとに、任意の文字を表示する方法？

Tags: linq

C♯、Asp.net mvc5で、データを取ってきてモデルのクラスに入れて、viewに表示させています。
プログラムとかあまりわからないのと、私は理解力がないので質問がおかしかったらすみません。
Linqでデータを取って来たときに、caseでデータが1の時は、「りんご」、2の時は「みかん」とviewで表示出来ると聞いたのですが、どうやるのか分からないので例や参考、やり方など教えて下さい。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

たとえば`int`型の`data`という変数があったとして、`data == 1`かどうかで文字列の値を変えたい場合**三項演算子**が利用できます。

```
@(data == 1 ? "りんご" : "みかん")
```

三項演算子は連続で書けるので、たとえば`data == 2`という条件を追加したい場合は

```
@(data == 1 ? "りんご" : data == 2 ? "みかん" : "その他")
```

のように記述できます。

ただこのような処理は複数個所で使われる可能性が高いですし、普通にメソッドを作成して`switch`ステートメントを使うなどしたほうが汎用的だと思います。

たとえば問題の値が`Hoge`エンティティに定義されている場合、

```
namespace WebApplication1.Views // TODO: 適当に変える
{
    public static class HogeHelper
    {
        public static string GetFruitName(this Hoge entity)
        {
            switch (entity.Data)
            {
                case 1:
                    return ""りんご;

                // TODO: 省略

                default:
                    return "その他";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

などと定義して、ビューまたは`Views/Web.config`で名前空間を参照すれば.cshtml中で`GetFuitName`拡張メソッドが使用できるようになります。

Comment: pgrhoさん、分りやすくありがとうございます。